# Converting Javafx application jar file to apk files (Netbeans)

Tags: java, android, javafx, javafxports

Is there a facility in netbeans that will automate the conversion of javafx jar file into apk files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, there is a way to create an Android application (apk) from a JavaFX application, based on the [JavaFXPorts](http://javafxports.org/page/home) project.

Recently, a new plugin has been released, so you can just 'drop it' on your JavaFX project and build the apk.

Have a look at the 'getting started' [guide](http://javafxports.org/page/Getting_Started). Basically, considering you are using NetBeans, you will need:

- JDK8u40 early access [release](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html) installed, JAVA_HOME should be set with the JDK path.
- [Gradle](https://gradle.org/) 2.2.1 installed
- Android [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html?pkg=tools)
- Android Build Tools 21.1.1 using SDK Manager.
- Gradle Plugin for NetBeans (optional)
- And the plugin which is a 'build.gradle' file

It looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:javafxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-rc3'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'javafxmobile'

mainClassName='org.javafxports.android.MainJavaFX'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

jfxmobile {
    android {
        applicationPackage = 'org.javafxports.android'
    }
}
```

I suggest you try the [Ensemble 8 project](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin-ensemble), clone the project, and see for yourself how easy it is to port this application to Android.

You can create new projects with the Gradle plugin, then add a JavaFX project, add the plugin, and it will create the apk as easy as:

```
gradlew android
```

Or you can use any existing JavaFX project with this build.gradle file.

**Important considerations**

The plugin works with the last JDK8 8u40, but it doesn't support all Java 8 features (Streams and Optional), while it supports Lambdas. On the contrary, it supports mainly all the JavaFX 8 features.

It's in working progress, so some issues may not been solved yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.

If you want to develop a `javafx` app on android:

> Use the JavaFX-Android SDK to generate an Android project based on
>   your JavaFX Application

see this: http://www.infoq.com/articles/Building-JavaFX-Android-Apps

Comment: Why not? I've seen demos javafx apps running on android.

Comment: if you want to create a javafx on android, Use the JavaFX-Android SDK to create an Android project based on your JavaFX Application

Comment: Is there a way that we can do this in netbeans?

Comment: yes, here's a guide setting up android sdk on netbeans : https://forums.netbeans.org/topic51543.html

Comment: As Jose correctly wrote in the answer, it is indeed possible to create JavaFX Android packages within NetBeans. The InfoQ article referred here mentions the "old" approach, which requires more building and configuring, and that didn't work out of the box with NetBeans.  Situation has improved since that article was published.